# How to add dot after \section number in headline and ToC, without adding dot to \ref command

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, numbering

I need `\section` (`\subsection`, `\subsubsection` ...) titles printed with dot after numbering.

Example:

1. My Title

For this purpose i use:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\normalfont \arabic{section}.}

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}

\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection\arabic{subsubsection}.}

\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsection\arabic{paragraph}.}
```

But this method also adds extra dot to `\ref{}` commands. So code "Look at section `\ref{section:label}`." produces string "Look at section 3.."

Is there any way to add dot only to headlines and ToC, but not to references?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do with `titlesec/titletoc`. The dot after the label is added by `\titleformat`, not by `\thesection`.  As for the dot in the table of contents, it is an option in titletoc. In addition, I use `cleveref` for a simpler writing of cross-references.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries\large}{Section \thesection.}{0.4em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
\dottedcontents{section}[3.8em]{}{2.3em}{1pc}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Preliminaries}\label{sec:prelim}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Another section}
See \Cref{sec:prelim}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
```

More information in [the `titlesec` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) on page 3.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i need extra dot also in ToC.

Comment: I would also like to know how to add the do in the ToC